# How to dynamically setup User Permission in JavaEE6

Tags: seam, java-ee-6

I'm currently working on a JavaEE6 project and I want to setup a dynamically assigned set of permissions to a user or role. In seam2, this can be achieved by org.jboss.seam.security.persistentPermissionResolver, I'm wondering if there's an equivalent approach or technology with JavaEE6. So far in Oracles's JavaEE6's documentation all I can see were setting the directory access in web.xml.

What's the best approach (real world) in JavaEE6 to setup authentication and authorization? Possibly through database or LDAP.

Thanks,

czetsuya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching for sometime, one of the best security technology out there that I was able to test was Apache Shiro. I'm happy with its fine-grained permission level control. So I'm using it for my JavaEE6 project. As to how I integrate both here's the link: http://czetsuya-tech.blogspot.com/2012/10/how-to-integrate-apache-shiro-with.html